# ssl certs signed by my employer for sites like gmail, twitter, facebook

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I noticed that when I try to access sites like Gmail, Facebook and Twitter while connected to corporate network, Firefox shows an 'untrusted certificate' error and I have to add an exception to access those sites. I don't get the same exception when I try to access sites like Amazon and Paypal. I looked at the certs causing the exceptions and they all have my employer 'XYZ Inc' as the CA. 
I am not that familiar with certs and wanted to know to know what is going on in the corporate network. How could Gmail serve a cert signed by my employer? When I access Gmail from home, I get the correct cert signed by Thawte.
Should I be worried about this and change my passwords for all the sites that cause the cert exception?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on certificates either, but it appears that your company is intercepting the SSL traffic, and to do that, they have to use their own certificates to encrypt the portion between your computer and the company firewall/gateway (?). You are probably getting an error because a) the CA is not trusted by your computer or / and b) the certificate CN (domain) mismatch.

May be nothing... but it appears something fishy is going on there.

Comment: Thanks. What would a company get by intercepting the traffic between my PC and gateway?

Comment: If they want to do content filtering (scan for virus, block by keywords, etc) they need to intercept and decrypt the connection, otherwise they have no way to do it (that's the whole purpose of HTTPS right?). That would be the "official" reason for it. I don't know the company, but the other reason would be a sysadmin with no personal life that simply likes to view other people's online life. In that case, you should raise this to the management.

Comment: I think. In either case, I would change the passwords right away and don't use those services in the corporate network. After all, the browser is telling you that something's not right with your security.